# A question on Likelihood Ratio testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

[image]

In part (a) of the given question I have derieved the UMP level alpha test using Neyman Pearson Lemma.

In part (b) it is asked whether LR level alpha test will match with UMP test.

Below is my approach..

[image]

So in the above process( given in picture), I have showed the Likelihood Ratio condition and NP lemma criteria for testing coincides. So the LR test will give same results as UMP test.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: You can use LaTeX mark-up for equations - easier to read & works with accessibility applications used by the visually impaired.

Comment: Sorry. I dont know much about LaTeX. Would try to present the question in a better form from next time onwards..

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.